# VS Code / Metals: How to debug Scala sbt project using remote Debugger?

Tags: scala, debugging, visual-studio-code, compilation, sbt

I know the question has been asked before in some variation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495320/how-to-debug-scala-sbt-project-in-vs-code), but I simply can not figure out how to debug my scala sbt project in VS Code (WSL). Can someone provide some detailed instruction on how to do that ? What does it mean to debug using (java) remote Debugger ?

When I run Metals doctor, it says that it can not even detect the build tool. From the terminal however I am able to run/compile the code just fine (F.e. saying sbt "testOnly *IngestionTaskTest").

I addded the following launch.json file after entering >Debug: Select and Start Debugging in command Pallette:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "scala",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "somename",
        "mainClass": "somepackage.SparkMain",
        "args": [],
        "jvmOptions": []
      }
```

But I receive `Class: sompackage.SparkMain not found`

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found out how to do it. These are the exact steps:

1.) Configure launch.json manually. First go to command pallette and say >Debug: Select and Start Debugging in command Pallette

2.) Then edit launch.json to look like this:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "gqd debugger",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": "8000",
    }
]
}
```

4.) Enable sbt debugger in build.sbt by adding the following line: `Test / javaOptions += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"`

5.) In the bash terminal say sbt Test/testOnly theTest

6.) Wait a few seconds until project & settings are loaded. Then press putton F5

(Tests refers to my unit tests). Hope it helps.